# Is Khaya more durable and a better flooring choice (based on quantitative hardness, density, etc.) than "genuine mahogany"?

Tags: wood-selection, hardwood

I am having a hard time placing Khaya/African mahogany. An article states:

> Varieties of mahogany include Honduran, South American, Peruvian, Bolivian, Cuban, Big Leaf and True. All of them are typically marketed together and sold as "genuine mahogany." Two other varieties differ slightly: African mahogany, because of its luster and hardness, **is considered superior to genuine mahogany** and is usually marketed separately from genuine. ([source](https://www.hunker.com/13401189/difference-between-mahogany-oak-wood))

However, this seems to be belied by the actual numbers. Per [The Wood Database](https://www.wood-database.com/african-mahogany/) African mahogany's Janka Hardness is marked "1,070 lbf (4,760 N)" which is not particularly high. I know there are mahogany varieties with lower numbers, but I don't think 4,760 N makes the timber impressive flooring material. [This site](https://cedarstripkayak.wordpress.com/lumber-selection/162-2/) gives a wide density range (0.5 – 0.85 1000 kg/m3)

What, more accurately, is African mahogany's density? I am very concerned about its durability and scratch resistance properties. How does it fare as flooring? What are other notable qualities of this timber?

Comment: Well FWIW I don't think anyone — well nobody sane at least — would use genuine mahogany for flooring! I wasn't really aware that African mahogany was sold for flooring, the pieces that I've worked with certainly would suggest hardness as their primary characteristic (it's noted as an easy-working wood here), so I would share your assessment that it doesn't make for an impressive flooring choice re. durability. Looks on the other hand... it could be very impressive. It is know for varying, as all woods can, and the harder examples are *noticeably* harder than the usual or typical stuff. [contd]

Comment: However, it is worth bearing in mind that certain varieties of pine were widely used for flooring, and pine floorboards have stood up well enough in constant service in some Victorian and earlier homes for 150+ years......

Comment: To be fair, that 150+ year old pine flooring is old-growth and is harder than modern pine...

Comment: So many species are sold as "mahogany" I'd wonder what the actual species is sold as mahogany flooring.

Comment: Given the noted mystery mix of species, and if "hardness" is something you want, I'd just go to the flooring store and use a spring loaded centerpunch on the back of a few samples. That'll give you a rough sense of how they rank.

Comment: @FreeMan, yeah that's absolutely true.... up to when it wasn't :-) Pine continued to be the default choice for floorboards in standard house builds in the UK through the entire 20th century. And it is still used today over here.

Comment: Eddie, you might read it correctly but just to point out the typo in my first Comment, I meant to say "would **not** suggest hardness as their primary characteristic".